# PlantUML Activity Diagram connect condition to other path

Tags: plantuml, activity-diagram

I have the following activity diagram in PlantUML (not finished till the END):

```
@startuml
start
:A;
:B;
:C;

if (D == TRUE?) then (YES)
 : E;
 : F;
 if (G?) then (no)
  stop
 else (Yes)
 :H;
 endif

else (NO)
 :I;
 :J;

 if(K?) then (Yes)
@enduml
```

[image: This is the result]

I want to achieve if K? is YES than connect it to E:

[image]

Has anyone an idea how to do that?

Comment: See 'goto' on https://plantuml.com/activity-diagram-beta